# Azure Data Factory Http Connector failing for PDF url - casting FileWebRequest error

Tags: http, pdf, azure-data-factory

I tried to test ADF Http Connector with below base url and anonymous authentication https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/65645c183d7741000d420205/adm-summary-of-changes.pdf

**I got below error -**
`ErrorCode=HttpFileFailedToRead,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,               Message=Failed to read data from http server. Check the error from http server：Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.FileWebRequest' to type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest'.,  Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.InvalidCastException,Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.FileWebRequest' to type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'`

Comment: What you want to do with this pdf copy it somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I want to copy to ADLS using copy activity. I set binary format while creating source and sink dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps to achieve your requirement.

First create a HTTP linked service with the above URL as Base URL.

[image]

Test the connection and create a binary dataset for it. Use this Binary dataset as source to the copy activity like below. Request method should be **GET**.

[image]

Now, create another binary dataset for ADLS gen2 and give target path. Here, give the `filename.pdf` in the filename of the dataset.

[image]

Give this to copy activity sink and execute the pipeline. It will be copied to Gen2 as pdf file and you can see the output.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I will try and upvote

Comment: Yes the http connector is working now with above configuration